# Why is left outer join not producing the right results here?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code and for some reason the left outer join is not producing the correct results.

```
Dim StudentCourseList = From stud in students
                        Group Join cour in courses 
                        on stud.id equals cour.id into joinedlist = Group
                        From j in joinedlist.defaultifempty
                        select stud
```

The count before the left outer join of students is 12 and courses is 4. However, after the join, the student count is 14 due to some reason. It should be 12 if not less than 12. Am I doing something wrong here?

Edit - The query is fine. The problems in with the courses list. It has repeating/duplicate items in it. The question now would be how to get the distinct results?

Comment: Post your data and expected output .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not posted your table data. So this is just an assumption.

> > Why count is 14?

If one student have more than one course for example having two course than it would result in two records.

Use group by and then select first like below query.

```
var query = from person in people
                    join pet in pets on person.Id equals pet.OwnerId into gj
                    from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    group person by person.Id into temp1
                    select temp1.First();
```

[here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6n06Ja) is working fiddle. sorry I am not a vb guy so posted answer in c#.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason there are more than one course is because course list is based on a date range.. so in some years there are more than one courses and like you said, two results are being produced. would disctinct work here or do I need to use group by only?